# :nth-child into three different groups

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to make three different groups with nth-child or other selectors?

I would like the first one separately, then a two group, a three group, a two group...

```
<ul>
  <li>1 (green)</li>
  <li>2 (blue)</li>
  <li>3 (blue)</li>
  <li>4 (red)</li>
  <li>5 (red)</li>
  <li>6 (red)</li>
  <li>7 (blue)</li>
  <li>8 (blue)</li>
  <li>9 (red)</li>
  <li>10 (red)</li>
  <li>11 (red)</li>
  <li>12 (blue)</li>
  <li>13 (blue)</li>
  <li>14 (red)</li>
  <li>15 (red)</li>
  <li>16 (red)</li>
  <li>17 (blue)</li>
  <li>18 (blue)</li>
  <li>19 (red)</li>
</ul>
```

The first one is no problem. But with nth-child I do not get further yet

```
li:first-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rtgh9u5q/ <-- based on the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in one of the options for solving your problem, you can use the combined pseudo-classes `:nth-child()` for a specific color, defining the order of lines.

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

li:nth-child(5n+2),
li:nth-child(5n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
}

li:nth-child(5n+4),
li:nth-child(5n+5),
li:nth-child(5n+6) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1 (green)</li>
  <li>2 (blue)</li>
  <li>3 (blue)</li>
  <li>4 (red)</li>
  <li>5 (red)</li>
  <li>6 (red)</li>
  <li>7 (blue)</li>
  <li>8 (blue)</li>
  <li>9 (red)</li>
  <li>10 (red)</li>
  <li>11 (red)</li>
  <li>12 (blue)</li>
  <li>13 (blue)</li>
  <li>14 (red)</li>
  <li>15 (red)</li>
  <li>16 (red)</li>
  <li>17 (blue)</li>
  <li>18 (blue)</li>
  <li>19 (red)</li>
</ul>
```